Azured AD JWT authentication doesn't work for Web API hosted in docker using TestContainer
I have an ASP .Net Web API hosted in Docker using TestContainer for integration tests. The Web API's endpoints are secured by using using JWT token and all this works very well when the Web API is hosted in production outside on IIS.
I get the exception
WWW-Authenticate: Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The audience 'api://XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX' is invalid"
Is there anything needed to be done for the Azure AD JWT authentication to work in TestContainers/Docker?
Thanks in advance.

Have you correctly set environment variables in docker for the Azure AD configuration like (AzureAd:Audience, AzureAd:Instance, and AzureAd:TenantId)

Those are there in the appSettings.json. Does that need to be set separately as environment variables as well? Will try setting the environment variables as well.

have you defined any custom scope to generate token for the application.

Nopes. Just the standard access_as_user.

Setting the AzureAd variables as environment variables of the TestContainer has worked.

Does my solution work for you or you still need any assistance?

I believe it has worked as mentioned in my last comment. Thanks for your help.


I get the exception WWW-Authenticate: Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The audience 'api://XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX' is invalid

To resolve the error, add AzureAD environment variables in the TestContainer:
AZURE_CLIENT_ID  -  App ID of the service principal
AZURE_TENANT_ID  - the Tenant ID
AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET  - Secret value of the service principal
You can get values of  AZURE_CLIENT_ID  and  AZURE_TENANT_ID  from app registration page that you can check below
Overview:

Create Client secret and add in environmental variables.

